# Training Neural network to predict sin(x) matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network, function-approximation

---

It's been 3 days since i'm trying to train many neural networks to predict sin(x) function, i'm using matlab 2016b (i have to work with it in my assignement)

what i did :

- change layers
- duplicate dataset (big , small)
- add/sub periods
- shuffle the data
- change neural's number per layer
- change learning function
- change the transfer function and mapped the target

all that with no good prediction, can anyone explain me what i'm doing wrong ,
 and it would be very helpful to paste any good book for ("preparing dataset befor traing", "knowing the best NN's structure for your project",...
and any book seems helpful)

my actual code : (i'm using nntool for the training )

```
%% input and target
input = 0:pi/100:8*pi;
target = sin(input) ;


plot(input,sin(input)),
hold on,

inputA = input;
targetA = target;
plot(inputA,targetA),
hold on,
%simulate input
output=sim(network2,inputA);
plot(inputA,output,'or')
hold off
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: done , i'm using nntool directly for the training

Comment: @MateenUlhaq if u can give me any book may help me to understand the concept i would appreciate it

Comment: have you tried a `narxnet` with enough Delays to cover a whole cycle (2pi)?

Comment: my assignement with matlab , feedforward NN